# Can I get the results from a regex into a new string?

Tags: regex, perl

I already know how to use regex to modify a string, i.e.

```
$string1 =~ s/[aeiouy]//gi;
```

But what's the syntax to keep the original string?  i.e.

```
$string2 = $string1 = s/[aeiouy]//gi;
```

So that $string1 is the before and $string2 is the after.

Am sure there is a way, thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way, if you have Perl 5.14 or better, is with the [`/r` modifier](https://metacpan.org/pod/perlop#s/PATTERN/REPLACEMENT/msixpodualngcer).

```
$string1 = "cat toy";
$string2 = ($string1 =~ s/[aeiouy]//gir);
print $string1;       # "cat toy", unchanged
print $string2;       # "ct t",    with modifications
```

It works with the transliteration operator, too

```
$string1 = "cat toy";
$string2 = ($string1 =~ tr/aeiouy/123456/r);
print $string1;       # "cat toy"
print $string2;       # "c1t t46"
```

Comment: Thanks, but what's the "r" in the `/gir` required for?  Seems to work the same without it.

Comment: No, it doesn't. Without the `/r` modifier, the substitution is performed on `$string1` and the value 3 is assigned to `$string2`.

Comment: I realize I am new at this, but `$string1 = ($string2 =~ s/[aeiouy]//gi);` works just the same as `$string1 = ($string2 =~ s/[aeiouy]//gir);`  I can find no difference.

Comment: what does the `/r` stand for?

Comment: Follow the link on `/r` in mob's answer... :-)

Comment: `\r` stands for "return substitution and leave original string untouched".